# Android studio remember account login. using django rest framework

Tags: android

how do i create an android app that will remember the user account? i have already login code, but every time i close the app and open it again, the user must not login again. how do i solve that? i have this documentation but its to hard to understand https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtUsername;
    EditText edtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    UserService userService;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        userService = ApiUtils.getUserService();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
           
                if(validateLogin(username, password)){
          
                    doLogin(username, password);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password){
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Intro_Pref",MODE_PRIVATE); ==> here, i am doing rigth?
        if(username == null || username.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        if(password == null || password.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return pref.getBoolean("isIntroOpened",false); == > 
    }
    private void savePrefsData() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Intro_Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isIntroOpened", true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void doLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        Call<UserService.AuthenticationResponse> call = userService.login(username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    UserService.AuthenticationResponse authResponse = (UserService.AuthenticationResponse) response.body();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authResponse.token)) {
                        //login start main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DestinationListActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", username);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The secure way to make this is generating a token with an expiration date on your backend and storing it on your app. Then you can check if the stored token is valid when your app launches.

Comment: can you please help me ? i cant follow you. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add shared preferences, like when user login makes login value true. If login value true then sends user direct splash to Home Activity, not login or signup activity. For save login value, you can follow this, Make sure this method is called from login success.

```
private void savePrefsData(boolean isLogin) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("ISLOGIN", isLogin);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Then check isuser login or not from splash activity, like this

```
public boolean isUserAlreadyLogin(){
SharedPreferences pref = 
    getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getBoolean("ISLOGIN",false);
}
```

Call this from SplashActivity.

```
if(isUserAlreadyLogin){
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LogInActivity.class));
}
```